# Which is the correct way to efficiently filter a numpy matrix by column values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am working with a numpy matrix like this:

```
[[   0    1    2 ...,   97   98  0]
 [ 100  101  102 ...,  197  198  0]
 [ 200  201  202 ...,  297  298  1]
 ...,
 [9700 9701 9702 ..., 9797 9798 1]
 [9800 9801 9802 ..., 9897 9898 0]
 [9900 9901 9902 ..., 9997 9998 0]]
```

How can I remove all the rows that have one in the last column of my numpy matrix?:

```
[[   0    1    2 ...,   97   98  0]
 [ 100  101  102 ...,  197  198  0]
 ...,
 [9800 9801 9802 ..., 9897 9898 0]
 [9900 9901 9902 ..., 9997 9998 0]]
```

I tried to transform the matrix into a pandas dataframe and filter by the last column:

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(data=second_round_mat[1:,1:])
matrix = matrix[matrix['567'] != 1.0]
```

However, this is not very convinient, and maybe there's a similar way to do that in numpy, thus how can I filter by column value in numpy?

Comment: arr[mask,:] where mask=arr[:,-1]==1

Comment: I got: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
`

Comment: Are you really  working with a numpy array?

Comment: yes, when I check the type I get: `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: You need to provide the actual code and traceback.  Indexing a `ndarray` should not produce this `TypeError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the rows like this directly in numpy:

```
matrix = matrix[matrix[:, -1] != 1]
```